Checkmarx : parameter tampering in Oracle SQL files
FUNCTION some_func (v_tableName_In IN VARCHAR2)
RETURN NUMBER
AS
v_tableName VARCHAR2(4000);

BEGIN

v_tableName := DBMS_ASSERT.sql_object_name(v_tableName_In);
v_tableName := sys.DBMS_ASSERT.noop(TO_CHAR(v_tableName_In));


This is a function which takes v_tableName_In as parameter, and checkmarkx is showing me issue of parameter tampering.
I have used DBMS_ASSERT.noop(), and also DBMS_ASSERT.sql_object_name() as suggested by chatgpt. But still the issue is not resolved
The 'sys.DBMS_ASSERT.noop()' statement helps me resolve SQL second order injection but not parameter tampering.
Can anyone please help me with this?

Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] with: the complete function; and the error message & line number from checkmarx. We cannot debug code that we cannot see and if the error relates to a line later in the function then we need to see that line.
